# Wordpress Export - Not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My wordpress export option is no longer functioning.

I get the error:

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://www.airport-game-lodge.co.za/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=all&cat=0&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_status=0&page_author=0&page_start_date=0&page_end_date=0&page_status=0&attachment_start_date=0&attachment_end_date=0&query=&submit=Download+Export+File might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

I have updated my Wordpress Version, as well as my export plugin - but it is still giving the same error ?

I can also not update or delete any plugins at all now ?

Update Failed: {"success":true,"data":{"update":"plugin","slug":"contact-form-7","oldVersion":"Version 3.2.1","newVersion":"Version 4.5","plugin":"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php","pluginName":"Contact Form 7"}}

Comment: what do you mean by Export Plugin, wordpress do not need any external export plugin to export posts, pages, attachements.

Comment: @Tarun Mahashwari Then how will move the WordPress from Local to Online Server Only with the help of Export Plugin Right :)

Comment: @Tarun Mahashwari If you are moving it manually you need to do double the works when you doing lots of work onto Theme Options. If you Use any Export plugins your works is reduced by millions of times.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I don't need to move the site. I would like to export contents of some plugins I have used.  Gravity forms - as their plugin export is not working, and also the Connections plugin (plugin export not working).   So therefore thought I could use the Standard wordpress export feature to export the contents of these plugins (the gravity forms - forms, and the 'Connections - staff)

Comment: Now I see that any plugin I try to export from - even for standard csv exports do not work, I get this error:
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://www.airport-game-lodge.co.za/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Answer (score 2):

Helpful for others - my problem was solved by updating my PHP version

Answer (score 0):

> WordPress `export option` may not work due to your `WordPress update` which may change the `data structure` or the `object key` that preventing the export option to work, but when you are exporting your WordPress from your `local PC` to your `server` it's better not to use the `export option as your`images` and URL will not work in your server.

you can easily upload your whole WordPress installation from your local PC to your server, you can get the details instruction from the below URL,

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

but the basic steps are simple

> i) export your database from local PC
>
> ii) upload your whole Local PC WordPress folder to your server
>
> iii) import the database to your server
>
> iV) change the option URL from imported database
>
> v) you may have to use the `velvet blues` wordpress plugin to fix the image urls

for uploading the folder if you use a server like `Heroku` you may just push your git repo to your server. To Deploy your app with git you can get detail documentation from below url,

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: I will try the above.   I can also not delete or update any other plugins now ?  Deletion failed: {"success":true,"data":{"delete":"plugin","slug":"wp-error-fix","plugin":"wp-error-fix\/wp-error-fix.php","pluginName":"CodePinch"}}

Comment: if your local PC WordPress installation creating problem than you may face the same problem in your server installation if you follow the above approch as it just create a copy of your local installation to your server, i hope this comment helps you to decide

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error - I deleted all comments made on my blog posts - most were spam anyway, and it worked straight away